# Creating an autokey cipher function

Tags: list-manipulation, functions

Can someone help me with putting what I can say in words into code.
I want to create autokey encrypt and decrypt functions (just wanting help encrypting and then can figure out decrypting). Everything is in Z 26.

The function would begin like:

```
autokeyEncrypt(x_, key_) :=
```

x is plaintext (e.g. rendezvous) and k is the key (e.g. 8), I first would need to convert the plaintext into a sequence of integers. I have a function to do this already that is used like:

```
stringToNumbers[x]
```

this would give

```
{17, 4, 13, 3, 4, 25, 21, 14, 20, 18}
```

Call this list `xlist`. The keystream then would be

```
{8, 17, 4, 13, 3, 4, 25, 21, 14, 20}
```

That is, the `key` argument prepended to `xlist`. Now form `xlist[[i]] + keystrean[[i]]` , reducing mod 26, and the resulting ciphertext (as numbers then letters) would be:

```
{25, 21, 17, 15, 7, 3, 20, 9, 8, 12}
ZVRQHDUJIM
```

I am familiar with java and wondering if there is a way to accomplish something with the structure similiar to

```
autokeyEncrypt(x, key) {
   x = stringToNumbers(x) 
   create list with just the key in it
   loop to take numbers from x and fill list (until reaches specific length)
   etc
```

Comment: You dropped the value 18 in the example above.  I don't know if this was intentional; I shall answer as if it were not.

Comment: Perhaps I don't understand what you mean by "add the elements, reducing mod 26" as I get a different result: `{8, 25, 3, 16, 19, 23, 22, 17, 5, 25, 17}`.  I'll use that until further clarification.

Comment: In your pseudo-code you say "until reaches specific length" -- where is that specified?

Answer (score 3):

Here is an implementation that reads almost like a literal translation of the problem statement:

```
stringToNumbers[x_] := ToCharacterCode @ ToUpperCase @ x - 65

autokeyEncrypt[x_String, key_Integer] :=
  Module[{xlist, keystream}
  , xlist = stringToNumbers[x]
  ; keystream = Most @ Prepend[xlist, key]
  ; FromCharacterCode[Mod[xlist + keystream, 26] + 65]
  ]

autokeyEncrypt["rendezvous", 8]
(* "ZVRQHDUJIM" *)
```